Why was IEEE 1532 withdrawn?
Official status of IEEE 1532 2002 is "Inactive-Withdrawn Standard" as it is stated here.
Analyzing the standards IEEE 1149.1 2001 and 2013 (and some version of 1149.7 and 1149.4) I have come to conclusion that IEEE 1532 was not embedded or somehow integrated in any of those. At least the term "In-System Cofniguration" (ISC), specific ISC registers and ISC instructions are not used in IEEE 1149.* that I enumerated earlier.
And I can't find any official information on why IEEE 1532 is being cancelled.
So, was it just cancelled or took part in another standard that currently is officially active? And if it was just cancelled, is it de-facto widely used nowadays?

TL;DR: It looked like a good idea that nobody bothered using anyway.
Perhaps a misunderstanding of the process of standardization is the source of your confusion: IEEE isn't some legislative body that makes up standards. They are just a convenient "umbrella" for people from academia and industry to come together to work on standards they need to make their own lives easier.
It was withdrawn mainly because it had no industry following. These standards are, after all, created by engineers from the industry and academia. If nobody has interest in using the standard and maintaining it, the standard dies. It was someone's (perhaps more than one someone) idea that they likely used at work. They thought it may be worth sharing, so the standard was written... and nothing much happened afterwards. Thus it died.

why hasn't Kuba forgotten about Monica?

@Ankit_Gunner Who or what is Monica and why so much notice from SE users?

damn, it was so deeper than I thought it would be, I really thought it would be a reference to a movie or TV. Thanks a lot @Andrew Morton
